# (SQL Server) Convert varchar to money while using AVG, MAX, MIN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, currency

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar, CAST(AVG(devMarketCap) AS money),1), 
'$' + CONVERT(varchar, CAST(MIN(devMarketCap) AS money),1), 
'$' + CONVERT(varchar, CAST(MAX(devMarketCap) AS money),1)

FROM developer
```

Could this be improved or shortened?

Comment: You should always use an explicit length when using `varchar()`.

Comment: What's the difference? I thought it only used what it needs to when I leave it blank.

If I do varchar(20) and the value is only 5 characters long, will it use 20 or 5?

Comment: [Declaring `VARCHAR` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)